# Angular + GRPC-WEB

Tags: angular, grpc-web

Using Angular 14 + GRPC-WEB

1. Create a GRPC Proto

```
  syntax = "proto3";

  package BPGRPC;

  service BP_GRPC_Service {
     rpc AddBloodPressure (BP_Request) returns (BP_Response);
  }

  message BP_Request {
     uint32  systolic = 1;
     uint32  diastolic = 2;
     uint32  pulse = 3;
     string  date = 4;

  }
 
  message BP_Response {
    string msg = 1;
    uint32 code =2;
    string last_updated = 3;
  }
```

2. Create a Angular Services - ./src/services/blood-pressure.service.ts

```
   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
   import { BrowserHeaders } from 'browser-headers'

   import { BP_GRPC_ServiceClient} from "../grpc/generated/BPGRPC_pb_service"
   import { BPGRPC_Module } from 'src/grpc/generated/BPGRPC_pb_module';
   import { BP_Request } from 'src/grpc/generated/BPGRPC_pb';


   @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
   })
   export class BloodPressureService {

  private client: BP_GRPC_ServiceClient;

  constructor() { 

    this.client = new BP_GRPC_ServiceClient ( 'http://localhost:50051');
  }

   public SaveBloodPressure (systolic : number, diastolic: number, pulse : number,
    date : string) {

    // Create the New Request
    const bloodPressureRequest = new BP_Request ()

    // setup the request
    bloodPressureRequest.setSystolic (systolic)
    bloodPressureRequest.setDiastolic (diastolic)
    bloodPressureRequest.setPulse (pulse)
    bloodPressureRequest.setDate (date)

    // Call this Client
    const headers = new BrowserHeaders();
    headers.set('custom-header-1', 'header value');
    this.client.addBloodPressure (bloodPressureRequest,headers, (error ,response ) => {
    
      if (error) {
        console.log("Code %d ",error?.code);
        console.log("Message %s ",error?.message)
      } else {
        console.log ("Response : %d ", response?.getCode())
        console.log ("Response : %s ", response?.getMsg())
    
      }
        });
     }  
     }
```

3. Create a Angular Module for the **Services**

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import {   BloodPressureService } from './blood-pressure.service';`
    
    @NgModule({
    declarations: [/* ... `*`/],
    imports: [/`*` ... */],
    providers: [BloodPressureService]
    })
    
    export class BloodPressureServiceModule { }
```

But the Problem when perform NG Build

```
\*\*\*./src/services/blood-pressure.service.ts:2:0-76 - Error: Module not found: Error: 

   Can't resolve   '../grpc/generated/BPGRPC_pb_service' in   

     '/Users/administrator/Documents/GitHub/End2EndIM/src/services'

   ./src/services/blood-pressure.service.ts:3:0-58 - Error: Module not found: Error: 

   Can't resolve     'src/grpc/generated/BPGRPC_pb' in   

  '/Users/administrator/Documents/GitHub/End2EndIM/src/services'\*\*\*
```

In Angular I installed all the components.

1. `npm install ts-protoc-gen @improbable-eng/grpc-web @types/google-protobuf google-protobuf`
2. Also Compile the Proto using

```
# Protoc Path

      PROTOC_PATH_DIR="grpc/protos"

# Directory to write generated code to (.js and .d.ts files)

    OUT_DIR="grpc/generated"
    mkdir -p ${OUT_DIR}
    
        protoc
           --plugin="protoc-gen-ts=${PROTOC_GEN_TS_PATH}"
           --ts_out="service=grpc-web:${OUT_DIR}"
          --proto_path="${PROTOC_PATH_DIR}"
           BPGRPC.proto
```

Comment: 1.-When you import a module, **NOT** import from '/src', your path is always "relative", I imagine: `import { BP_Request } from '../../grpc/generated/BPGRPC_pb';`. 2.- You **not** import a module in a component nor service. The modules are import only in another modules

Answer (score 0):

look at [ng-grpc](https://github.com/ngx-grpc/ngx-grpc) documentation, it seems you missed the config grpc-we module in your app module.

in you app module add
GrpcCoreModule.forRoot(),
GrpcWebClientModule.forRoot({settings: { host: "host-address" }}),

Answer (score 0):

For anyone struggling with this: Include --js_out as well while generating the typescript code:

**Also, use absolute path instead of relative.**

```
protoc --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc-web=./node_modules/.bin/protoc-gen-grpc-web.cmd --js_out=import_style=commonjs:./types --grpc-web_out=import_style=typescript,mode=grpcwebtext:./types --proto_path=./Protos protofile.proto
```

Dependencies:

- @improbable-eng/grpc-web: `npm i @improbable-eng/grpc-web`
- grpc-web: `npm i grpc-web`
- protoc-gen-grpc-web: `npm i protoc-gen-grpc-web`
- google-protobuf: `npm install --save google-protobuf` `npm install --save-dev @types/google-protobuf`